# Open anonimized ATM transactions dataset

Tags: data-request

I have a hard time to find an open data with ATM transactions. I need to train a machine learning model for detecting frauds. This is my Master theses topic.

I know that this is a very sensitive topic. That's why even the tiniest hint will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I found one on Kaggle:

**[ATM Transaction Data of City Union Bank](https://www.kaggle.com/nitsbat/atm-transaction-data-of-city-bank/data)**

```
atm_name,String
transaction_date,DateTime
no_of_withdrawals,Numeric
no_of_cub_card_withdrawals,Numeric
no_of_other_card_withdrawals,Numeric
total_amount_withdrawn,Numeric
amount_withdrawn_cub_card,Numeric
amount_withdrawn_other_card,Numeric
weekday,String
festival_religion,String
working_day,String
holiday_sequence,String
```

[image]